# PHP array mysql retrieve each record

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

- Database (book table)
   
  serialID           price
   0001              10.00
   0001             
  30.00
   0002              15.00
   0003(A)          9.00
   0004(B)          5.00
   0005               3.00
- Code

  ```
  $serialID = array("0001","0002","0003","0004","0005");

  //DB Connection
  for($i = 0; $i < count($serialID); $i++)
  {
      $q = "select serial from book where serial like \"$serialID[$i]\" limit 1";
      $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
  }

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
  {
      echo $row['serial'].'<br />';
  }
  ```
- From my code,  I can only get the last serialID only. How do I retrieve every **serialID** in `$row`?

Comment: put your while loop inside for loop. As while loop will run only for last result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead :

```
$q = "select serial from book where serial like '%"
   . implode($serialID, "%' OR serial LIKE '%") . "%'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
   echo $row['serial'].'<br />';
```

In your `for` loop you `SELECT` all of the rows, but only the last instance is saved in a variable ( in the last iteration of the `for` loop), so you fetch only it in the `while` loop.

*P.S. You could also work it out by putting your `while` loop in the end of the `for` loop, but the code above is just not that cumbersome.*

Answer (score 0):

Edit: you always override your select statement in the for loop before quering it. So only the last query with the last serial is executed

Answer (score 0):

i hope you have did a mistake that in the query you have kept limit 1 so that's the reason you are getting only last record

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($serialID); $i++)
{
$sql=select serial from book where serial like \"$serialID[$i]\"
$r = mysqli_query($sql);
}

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)
 {
 echo $row['serial'].'<br />';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$serialID = array("0001","0002","0003","0004","0005");

//DB Connection
foreach($serialID as $serial){
    $q = "select serial from book where serial like '%".$serial."%' limit 1";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)
        echo $row['serial'].'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for($i = 0; $i < count($serialID); $i++)
{
$r = mysqli_query($sql);
$sql=select serial from book where serial like "$serialID[$i]"
}

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)
 {
 echo $row['serial'].'<br />';
  }
```